# typedef NS_ENUM: passing an NSDictionary of custom properties to method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsenumerator

I've created a macro like this, and a definition:

```
#define CustomImageOptions NSDictionary
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CustomImageOption) {
    CustomImageOptionResize, // CGSize
    CustomImageOptionQuality, // CGFloat
    CustomImageOptionType // NSString (JPEG or PNG)
};
```

I've got a method like this:

```
- (UIImage*)imageModifiedWithOptions:(CustomImageOptions*)options;
```

where i'd like to pass a dictionary of options to it like so (pseudo code):

```
[self imageModifiedWithOptions:@{CustomImageOptionResize: CGSizeMake(10, 20), CustomImageQuality: 0.9}];
```

It won't compile, presumably because my macro is of type NSInteger, which is not enumerable as a key for NSDictionary.

How can I implement this so I can pass an NSDictionary of options to my method?

Comment: I'm confused. You have a #define that renames CustomImageOptions to be NSDictionary, then an unrelated TYPEDEF after that.  What are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Uh, well, I'm being silly I know. It's more for aesthetics than anything. I don't care so much about that, I care about being able to pass an NSDictionary of custom properties.

Comment: The keys to an NSDictionary must be objects.

Comment: Yes... I can see that in the compiler error. I'm asking how I can implement it.

Comment: ??? Pass objects as keys, not integers.

Comment: Yeah, so I could create some static NSStrings to use those as keys, but then I can't enforce the type of object passed. Is the only other way to do this to create a subclass of NSObject with enforced properties?

Comment: It's one of the blessings of duck typing.  All-in-all, I'll take it over Java's retentive "generics" any day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
[self imageModifiedWithOptions:@{@(CustomImageOptionResize): CGSizeMake(10, 20), @(CustomImageQuality): 0.9}];
```

They need to be converted to `NSNumber`s first.

Comment: By type checking I am assuming you mean ensuring the "key" is a proper `CGImageOption`? Yes, you're correct. The dev should use some asserts or other validation checks to ensure the key value is within the appropriate range.